# Kid spies on neighbour who might be a serial killer

Tags: identify-this-movie

So I am dying to find out about the movie title once again but i believe I mixed up some details from similar movies, but here it goes.

The movie is a few years old I would guess not older than 2005.

It's a thriller/horror film

The main character is around 18 years old and a male, He got grounded from school (for punching teacher in face?) And he would spend most of his time in his room playing videogames mostly.

These next details might be a little wrong but this is how I remember them, will be very short.

*One day he gets a new neighbor around the same age as he is, and becomes interested, they started to hang out, I guess she is new in town.

- Main character gets a telescope one day as a gift so he can do something useful while just sitting around in the room. He uses it check out the neighbors and what not.
- One late night he sees his other neigbor (Male about 50, living alone) dragging a bag what looks like to be a human body in there.

*So the main character and the girl next door decides to check it out and break into his garage but only to find out it was a deer roadkill.

*he keeps spying on this one neighbor since he seems suspicious and actually witnesses him killing another female in his home what looked to be a hooker.

- End up that he actually is a seriálkiller and has a lot of dead bodies in his basement hidden.

I am really sorry If I am not making sense but I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: Very well written Identify This question.

Comment: Ha, it sounds like the Simpsons episode, Bart of Darkness. Though I think that was a parody of Rear Window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [Disturbia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disturbia_%28film%29) from 2007:

> 17-year-old high school student Kale Brecht (Shia LaBeouf) is sued by his teacher for aggravated assault [...] He is secured with an ankle monitor and allowed only 100 feet from his house. After Kale's mother, Julie (Carrie-Anne Moss), cuts him off from television, video games and music to keep costs down and to get him to be more creative around the house, Kale begins to develop cabin fever and starts spying on his neighbors, including Robert Turner (David Morse), a man who is having an affair with his cleaning maid, the boys next door who occasionally play pranks on Kale, and the new neighbor, Ashley Carlson (Sarah Roemer) [...] Kale and Ronnie begin to research Turner after Kale witnesses several strange occurrences at Turner's house and thinks Turner might be a serial killer.

At first they find a bloody bag, but it turns out to be a dead deer. The film eventually ends in the way you've described (he finds a lot of dead bodies). Here's the trailer:

Comment: Wow, you are correct would never have found it myself!

Comment: I honestly appreciate it so much, It may not be as good as i remember but I will definitely watch it right now.

Comment: @DavidGöranLindkvist No problem and enjoy. :) Don't forget to close the question by clicking on the V sign.

Comment: Can not find any V sign, do you prefer me not deleting the thread?

Comment: It's the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Disturbia came out in 2007.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Corrected.